# I have default code errors due to initialisation interruption, how can I re-initialise it all?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, installation

### Background to issue:

I clean installed the latest Android Studio and it installed fine. The only thing I customized was the installation directory (Added one level). When it finished, I allowed it to auto-run Android Studio, and it instantly started.
So I started a new empty view activity project and named it "My First Application" (My "what's new" tester project). It opened the project and started *doing stuff* in the taskbar. I assume it always *does this* on a fresh installation (because when I created a new project later, it didn't *do it* again). But all of a sudden, after a few seconds, Android Studio just blinked out without warning. I waited in case it was restarting, but nothing happened, so I started it manually, and it seemed to carry on *doing stuff* for a couple seconds, then it blinked out again. I waited, then started it manually for the second time. This time it stayed on, which is where we get to the current issue.

### Current issue

[image: IDE with 20 error codes in source code (mostly reference errors)]

Apparently there were now 20 errors in the default project code. Mostly reference errors, so I assume some dependencies are missing due to the interruption.

### What have I tried so far?

I closed the project and opened a new one. Same issues. I uninstalled it and re-installed AS, and then it said 22 errors (but later went back to 20). I attempted to find an official dedicated Google/Android Studio dev help community (they did exist before) but was unsuccessful, so [I posted where I ended up](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/262789005?hl=en). They suggested I create a bug report [which I did](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/328691359). But I'm still stuck with 20 error codes.

### My question

As I am completely new to this current AS experience, I have no idea of where to look or how to check if the project dependencies have initialised correctly, which I assume is what AS was doing. I have no idea what the references are actually referencing right now, but I'm sure finding out wouldn't fix the problem. So while I'd like to know *why* it crashed, I don't actually care if I can just fix the errors by repeating - successfully this time - whatever it was doing when it crashed.
So ***how can I fix this?*** If I get it to re-do what it was doing when it got interrupted, it may just crash again (I know the popular definition of *"insanity"*). So I understand I may also need to learn *WHY* it happened.

### System Details

- Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1
  - Build #AI-232.10227.8.2321.11479570, built on February 21, 2024
  - **Runtime version:** 17.0.9+0--11185874 amd64
  - **VM:** OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
  - Windows 11.0
  - **GC:** G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
  - **Memory:** 4060M
  - **Cores:** 32
  - **Registry:** ide.experimental.ui=true
- **CPU:** i9-13900K
- **Chipset:** Intel z790
- **OS:** Windows 11 Pro | Version 22H2 | build 22621.1992

### References/Data

You can download the diagnostics from the [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/328691359), which includes metrics.

Comment: The displayed errors are errors found in the source code. That may be caused because the crash interrupted the compilation of your source code and it is now in an inconsistent state. You could try fixing those by synching gradle and doing a rebuild. The other problem is that Android Studio crashed in the first place. Right now it is unclear what your question is. Can you update your question to be more explicit about what specific problem you try to fix? If there are multiple problems, please create multiple questions, each one with a detailed description of the errors you experience.

Comment: Hi @Leviathan! Yes, I guessed that it got interrupted. I did have two questions really, _"Why?"_ and _"How do I fix it?"_ but, well, you just answered one, I think! Thanks for that. I'll try the Gradle thing. Maybe the "Why" is in the diagnostic files.

Comment: The Gradle sync and rebuild did nothing, but the "Repair IDE" cleaning steps fixed it, but I had to utilise every step and re-initialise indexes, dependencies and then invalidate caches. If the question is not on-topic or messy, edit or close it. If it's useful, I'll answer it later (or someone else can).